# Use an array without declaring it in a variable

Tags: java, arrays

If you try to do `15/2` it will return `7` because it thinks that `15` and `2` are integers. If you do `(double)15/2` it will return `7.5` because it knows that `15` is a double.

Say you have a function named `test()` that takes in an array as an argument. How would you pass an array into the function without defining it first?

I have tried doing something like this:

```
test((int[]){1,2,3,4})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close. You can do it like this:

```
test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (aka varargs), something like

```
public static double test(int... vals) {
    return IntStream.of(vals).sum() / (double) vals.length;
}
```

can be called with any number of `int`(s). For example,

```
System.out.println(test(1, 2, 3));
```

Which outputs

```
2.0
```